# Realizar una Resta en base al registro anterior SQL

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

Actualmente tengo el siguiente Script

```
SELECT 
 p.NumCredito
,p.Fecha
,p.Capital
,p.Interes
,SUM(p.Capital) + SUM(p.Interes) TotalCuota
,p.MontoOriginal
FROM dbo.Plan p
WHERE p.NumCredito = '0342341'
```

el cual me arroja es básicamente un plan de pago de un crédito, el mismo me arroja el siguiente resultado

```
NumCredito     Fecha      Capital     Interes     TotalCuota     MontoOriginal
 0342341     2023-01-01    400          500          900             50000 
 0342341     2023-02-01    400          500          900             50000
 0342341     2023-03-01    400          500          900             50000
 0342341     2023-04-01    400          500          900             50000
 0342341     2023-05-01    400          500          900             50000
```

lo que quiero es agregar un nuevo campo que se llame **Saldo** que vaya restando el TotalCuota del MontoOriginal

Este es el resultado que quiero

```
NumCredito     Fecha      Capital     Interes     TotalCuota     MontoOriginal     Saldo    
 0342341     2023-01-01    400          500          900             50000         50000
 0342341     2023-02-01    400          500          900             50000         49100
 0342341     2023-03-01    400          500          900             50000         48200
 0342341     2023-04-01    400          500          900             50000         47300
 0342341     2023-05-01    400          500          900             50000         46400
```

estaba pensando en usar una CTE, pero no se como ir restando en base al saldo anterior

como podría obtener ese resultado

Comment: con una funcion ventana (over)

Comment: honestamente soy un poquito nuevo, como seria exactamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir de los datos que proporcionas, el esquema quedaría así:

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE PlanPagos (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    NumCredito VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    Capital INT NOT NULL,
    Interes INT NOT NULL,
    MontoOriginal INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

-- data
INSERT INTO PlanPagos
    (Id, NumCredito, Fecha, Capital, Interes, MontoOriginal)
VALUES
    (1, '0342341', '2023-01-01', 400, 500, 50000),
    (2, '0342341', '2023-02-01', 400, 500, 50000),
    (3, '0342341', '2023-03-01', 400, 500, 50000),
    (4, '0342341', '2023-04-01', 400, 500, 50000),
    (5, '0342341', '2023-05-01', 400, 500, 50000)
;
```

Luego, el script que puedes usar sería este:

```
SELECT 
 p.NumCredito
,p.Fecha
,p.Capital
,p.Interes
,p.Capital + p.Interes TotalCuota
,p.MontoOriginal
,p.MontoOriginal - SUM(p.Capital + p.Interes) OVER (PARTITION BY p.NumCredito ORDER BY p.Fecha) Saldo
FROM PlanPagos p
WHERE p.NumCredito = '0342341'
ORDER BY p.fecha
```

Para obtener el saldo en cada registro, puedes usar la función `SUM` junto a la cláusula `OVER` para calcular el acumulado del capital + los intereses, luego restas el acumulado del monto original.

*Intenta y si tienes dudas, deja tu comentario.*

Creo que la salida es la que esperas...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Diría que para obtener el  saldo del crédito, al monto original solo se le resta la suma del capital pagado, y no la suma de la cuota total. Sé que el error es del AP y no tuyo, y que no tiene que ver con SQL sino con el negocio, pero igual me parece válido comentarlo.

Comment: @jachguate estoy de acuerdo. Si es solo para hacer una proyección de un crédito en un app, personalmente no le delegaría esa tarea al motor de base de datos. Pero, desconociendo el contexto, fue la solución que se me ocurrió. Solo queda esperar los comentarios del OP.

Comment: En SO en español decimos AP, de **A**utor del **P**ost y no como en SO en inglés: OP, de **O**riginal **P**oster. Lo comento por si no estabas informado, no por cambiar tu libre elecciön. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Dudo que sea la forma más eficiente, pero si la más fácil.

Es crear una subconsulta que sume los montos mayores a la fecha en cuestión

```
select 
 C1.NumCredito,
 C1.NumCredito,
 C1.Fecha,
 C1.Capital,
 C1.Interes,
 C1.Capital + C1.Interes as TotalCuota,
 C1.MontoOriginal,
 C1.MontoOriginal - COALESCE((select sum(C2.Capital + C2.Interes) from creditos as C2 where c1.fecha>c2.fecha),0)  as Saldo
from creditos as C1
```

Resultado:

| NumCredito | NumCredito | Fecha | Capital | Interes | TotalCuota | MontoOriginal | Saldo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0342341 | 0342341 | 2023-01-01 | 400 | 500 | 900 | 50000 | 50000 |
| 0342341 | 0342341 | 2023-02-01 | 400 | 500 | 900 | 50000 | 49100 |
| 0342341 | 0342341 | 2023-03-01 | 400 | 500 | 900 | 50000 | 48200 |
| 0342341 | 0342341 | 2023-04-01 | 400 | 500 | 900 | 50000 | 47300 |
| 0342341 | 0342341 | 2023-05-01 | 400 | 500 | 900 | 50000 | 46400 |